# How to write a string in Stringrid with DelimitedText in FMX Delphi 11

Tags: csv, delphi, firemonkey

In VCL, I use this line in the procedure for loading data from a `.csv` file:

```
StringGrid1.Rows[i].Assign(SRow);
```

But, in FMX, there is no property `Rows[]` so that I can insert delimited text with a line.

I can use `StringGrid1.Cells[i,j]`, but then I'll have to handle the delimiters myself.

How to write a string to a `TStringrid` with `DelimitedText` in FMX?

Comment: "*but then I'll have to handle the delimiters myself*" - not really.  You've already split the text into `SRow`, which has to be a `TStrings`-derived object in order for the VCL code to work properly. So, just loop through `SRow.Strings[]` assigning each one to a `Cell` on the desired row.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Thank you very much! Everything worked out! Here is the procedure code that worked. `StringGrid1.Cells[j,i]:=SRow.Strings[j];`